# 'Procedure or function 'GenerateTest' expects parameter '@questionnaireID', which was not supplied.'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Please help. I am inserting records with no issue. I would like to insert a random generated variable to the database on page load. The variable is being generated because it is showing up on the webpage. Is this just not possible since it's during Page_Load? Here's my code:

aspx:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Random r = new Random();
            questionnaire_id = r.Next(9000);

            Response.Write(questionnaire_id);
            FillSRETable();     // Table coming up. This is another stored procedure being called but only for viewing
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            GenerateNumber();
        }
        private void GenerateNumber()
        {
            if (sqlConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                sqlConnection.Open();
            Response.Write("Generated ID: " + questionnaire_id);

            SqlCommand sqlGenCmd = new SqlCommand("GenerateIDTest1", sqlConnection);
            sqlGenCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            sqlGenCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@questionnaire_id", questionnaire_id);
            sqlGenCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
```

I also took the GenerateNumber() function out and put it directly in the Page_Load function but still got the same error. I tried attaching it to a button, but nothing is firing off. It works fine in SSMS.

My procedure:

```
CREATE PROC GenerateIDTest1
@questionnaireID int
AS
BEGIN
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Questionnaire ON; 
INSERT INTO Questionnaire(questionnaire_id)
VALUES (@questionnaireID)
END
```

Comment: You see that underscore in the parameter name in C#? You see the lack of an underscore in the parameter name in the SQL/Error message?

Comment: Not a crucial since you are using stored procedures but AddWithValue has very interesting quirks. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Yea, I just copied and pasted and looked over the change I made in my procedures. Thanks so much because this was driving me crazy

Answer (score 4):

Your SQL command is adding the parameter @questionnaire_id, but your procedure is expecting the parameter @questionnaireID